# obtain values in dataframe instead of boolean

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe of calculated distances as following,

```
x_y_data = pd.read_csv("x_y_points400_labeled_20pnts_csv.csv")
x = x_y_data.loc[:,'x']
y = x_y_data.loc[:,'y']
xs=x.to_numpy()
ys=y.to_numpy()
result = pd.DataFrame(np.sqrt((xs[:, None] - xs)**2 + (ys[:, None] - ys)**2))
```

i get the results for all distances,

```
           0          1          2   ...         10         11         12
0    0.000000  16.132750  33.039985  ...  17.628989  27.273213  20.898938
1   16.132750   0.000000  16.912458  ...  16.658800  17.480346  25.375308
2   33.039985  16.912458   0.000000  ...  27.985766  19.625398  37.343842
3   10.140420  25.301309  41.896450  ...  20.173079  32.241763  18.523634
4    9.368331   9.228014  25.210365  ...  10.518585  18.039020  17.464249
```

now when I want to obtain only the values of the dataframe that are less than 12 
(by simply adding `result2=result<12`) I obtain the table of boolean,

```
 result2:
           0      1      2      3      4   ...     8      9      10     11     12
0    True  False  False   True   True  ...  False  False  False  False  False
1   False   True  False  False   True  ...  False  False  False  False  False
2   False  False   True  False  False  ...   True  False  False  False  False
3    True  False  False   True  False  ...  False   True  False  False  False
4    True   True  False  False   True  ...  False  False   True  False  False
```

where I want just the values that are less than 12 and not equal to zero. can you please help?

Comment: Don't assign the mask to the DataFrame, instead slice by the mask; `result[result < 12]` And if you want to get rid of the `NaN` then do `result[result < 12].stack()` You'll get a MultiIndex of (P1, P2) that satisfy your distance.

Comment: can you elaborate please? i tried both ways , it still prints the boolean of all values , not the values that are less than 12

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
result[result < 12].fillna('Morethan12')
```

or

```
result[result < 12].unstack().fillna('Morethan12')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give condition to show values based on   `0<result2<12`